# Vertx http server only creating one instance

Tags: java, vert.x

I am creating a simple micro service using vertx and when i start my server it only create one event thread when available is 12.

My code to start server is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    int processorCounts = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions().setInstances(processorCounts);
    vertx.deployVerticle( HttpRouter.class.getName(),options);
}
```

And my http router looks like this

```
@Override
public void start() throws Exception {
    super.start();
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    router.get("/").handler(event -> {
        event.response().end("Hello World");
    });
    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8001);
}
```

Comment: This might give you answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709931/vertx-scaling-the-number-of-instances-per-thread

Comment: @Quintium I have gone through documentation and i m familiar with concept that each verticle by default is on one event thread thats why i set number of instances for a verticle but only one verticle is handling all my requests.

Comment: It's looking like no different what I have done in tests myself. How you determine it? Looking current thread name in handler code?

Comment: @Quintium Actually verticles instances are launched but event thread is one so if any verticle block it then no more request is processed. So shall i use rxjava to create new threads or use blockingHandler ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your process for testing? I assume you opened a browser and hit refresh on the same page. Then yes, the same verticle instance will handle the requests. The reason is Vert.x load balances ***connections*** among verticles instances, not ***requests***.

Open a different browser and you should see different event loop names.

Comment: Actually i am getting more clearity on how verticles work. As per my understanding there is only one event thread and that load balances between all verticles because i sleeped thread in one of verticle and it stopped accepting any more request. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: NEVER block the event loop!

Comment: @LakshayJain No, your assumption is incorrect. There are different event loop threads (by default 2*number of cores). But each verticle is assigned a single event loop. So, when you deploy multiple verticle instances, each instance gets its own event loop. And Vert.x load balances HTTP connections between them.

Comment: @tsegismont: You are correct there is one thread blocked for each browser. So how can i resolve this so that each browser use multiple threads?

Comment: No thread is "blocked". Browsers use persistent HTTP connections so after you opened a tab the same verticle will handle requests from that page. Your users will use different browsers of course :)

Comment: @tsegismont If i use proxy using nginx will this use one loop or multiple loops?

Comment: It depends on how you configure nginx. Usually nginx is configured to manage a pool of persistent connections. So each one will get to a different verticle instance. I believe the original question has been answered so if you have other side questions please use the Vert.x forum where the community would gladly answer.