# Vertx thread shared memory

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, vert.x

I am trying to build a multithreaded system on Vertx Server. Our system will receive concurrent requests. I have a single event loop runing with 20 worker models. I am worried that since I am passing variables by reference between functions.

Now my question is that does each Thread share the memory pool which might cause the thread to fetch older value of the variable? or will Vertx handle this internally?

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709931/vertx-scaling-the-number-of-instances-per-thread/40716321#40716321

Answer (score 0):

Since vertx itself is asynchronous,no need to introduce other thread apis. After set WorkerPoolName, workerPoolSize and setInstances to handle the level of concurrency.