# What's the purpose of Verticle instance number and worker pool size coexist

Tags: vert.x

I am confuse about those 2 options, it seems only one is enough. Either 1 instance with multiple worker threads or multiple instance with only one worker thread can consume all cpu cores.

What is the purpose to deploy multiple instance and each instance has multiple worker thread? This seems meaningless.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertx scaling the number of instances per thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709931/vertx-scaling-the-number-of-instances-per-thread)

Comment: That question's answer paste many official docs which I had read already. But that could not answer: "why not just set a bigger worker thread pool size if user want to scale?" Instead, it choose deploy multi instance. However,  I cannot see any difference with set worker thread pool size, because all instances are running in single jvm, it can not across physical machines. So what is the meaning of this concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I do some tests agaist vertx 3.9, I found its threading model is unique. Vert.x can guarantee deployed non-worker verticle object always run in same thread even the callback handler like `Handler<AsyncResult>`. So if you only deploy one instance verticle, there will be only one thread to run codes belong to that verticle. If the verticle is worker, callback handlder will be run on different thread(worker thread pool size > 1), however, vertx do sync on it, thread safety still gets guaranteed. Besides that, worker thread pool size affect executeBlocking, if order parameter is false, the code will be concurrent without thread safety. If order is ture, code will be run by one specified thread.

The conclusion is: for non worker verticle, the only way to scale is deploy multiple verticle instance. for worker verticle, one instance with suitable worker thread pool size is enough. Of course it can be deployed more than one instance, however, that will not bring additional effect.

In order to solve communication between verticle instance(run by different thread,
risk of race condition), it introduce eventbus to decouple. All it trys to do is let user code to be concurrent without dive multithread knowledge ocean too deep. However, the weakness is obvious: the wrap is too thick(netty--vertx--(kotlin coroutine)) and doc is too brief. If user want to configure out "does this incurr a race condition?" That will be nightmare, will waste a lot time to figure out. If you can not grasp netty and want to concurrent easier, try golang. vertx+kotlin hidden too much inner things, a race condition might crash your jvm process...

Answer (score 0):

your question is like asking "why open multiple connections if there is a connection pool size?"

so obviously one is the number of each type of verticle that will run inside a pool of available thread pool and the other is the total pool size which translates to number of concurrent verticle instances that run at same time. I don't know if that is clear for you but if not, you probably need to revisit basics of threading.

Comment: I don't think that is "obviously", just like your answer just describe how rather than why.